# ajax doesn't work properly using horsey plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to have something like this ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function gettheresults() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url : '{{ path("client_medical_category_search") }}',
            data: 'asas',
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result);
                horsey(document.querySelector('#ssSearchParam'), {
                    suggestions: result,
                    limit: 10
                });
            }
        });
    }
    gettheresults();
</script>

<input value="{{ ssSerachParam }}" id="ssSearchParam" name="ssSearchParam" type="text" class="form-control"
               placeholder="{{'Search for clinic, treatment, doctor'|trans}}">
```

I am loading results via ajax from database. But it gets the results only after 1~3 seconds and it doesn't attaches to my input field anymore. If i do console.log(), i see the results are good. If i do without ajax, via PHP, it attaches ok. But i need this via ajax. What is the problem here, how can i make it to be attached to my search input field after delayed time?

I need horsey for fuzzyesearch. This ajax call is for mainly for horsey, that my fuzzysearch would have the results in which it would search. And it should append to my input field.

I have working only this part:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    void function () {
        'use strict';

        horsey(document.querySelector('#ssSearchParam'), {
            suggestions: ['airia', 'argentina', 'germany', 'etc'],
            limit: 10
        });

    }();

});
```

I need to get the suggestions to horsey via ajax.

Comment: Not the only problem, but your first call to `gettheresults()` should be in a DOM ready handler. If the results were cached then the control it updates would not exist yet (as it follows in the DOM). Are you able to mockup your page (e.g. in a JSFiddle)?

Comment: Also I note you have a typo: `ssSerachParam` instead of `ssSearchParam` in the `input`.

Comment: yes, there are some typos. Im fixing old website, and cant change many things without bleeding day :) So im leaving as it is. The website is very big and  i cant jsfiddle any part of it, it sends a huge request and gets huge response.

Comment: @mansim 1) You say "it doesn't attach ... anymore"... so this worked once? 2) How is your PHP-only code (that works)? 3) Try and call `$(document).ready(gettheresults)` instead of `gettheresults()`directly, maybe #ssSearchParam does not exist when horsey is called.

Comment: yes it works with document.ready(), but i dont know how exactly it would work with ajax call.

Comment: Declaring a function inside DOM ready is actually pointless. Only code that executes jQuery operations against the DOM need to be inside DOM ready. It is the calling code that needs to happen after the DOM is ready.